# Assets not working in rails containerised app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, assets

I am trying to setup ruby on rails application from docker everything is fine there is only one issue assets not load in application in docker. Please tell me how to resolve this issue.

### Asset compile log

---

** Execute assets:precompile
I, [2022-06-21T14:19:36.070795 #8]  INFO -- : Writing /var/www/quickcard/public/assets/admins_stylesheet-ee5c0de3bf28ba61ee5aae648b5394561912c52f237e45b9afd8b1dbaba97ddd.css
I, [2022-06-21T14:19:36.071640 #8]  INFO -- : Writing /var/www/quickcard/public/assets/admins_stylesheet-ee5c0de3bf28ba61ee5aae648b5394561912c52f237e45b9afd8b1dbaba97ddd.css.gz
I, [2022-06-21T14:19:36.072396 #8]  INFO -- : Writing /var/www/quickcard/public/assets/flags-38025784bedeb5e4cae496b131c85cabbd95ae0b1c0a3c9d9cb474d7262db04b.png
I, [2022-06-21T14:19:36.074876 #8]  INFO -- : Writing /var/www/quickcard/public/assets/flags@2x-e21becc4db003c08194a77f3311709fc0002a99be5dd18e8a5ba661c0472dc35.png
I, [2022-06-21T14:19:36.582968 #8]  INFO -- : Writing /var/www/quickcard/public/assets/application-4bcda1a2ad86133d1f3e33b2c53561990c0bd5c5e237e227357708bb00a21e7d.css
I, [2022-06-21T14:19:36.583732 #8]  INFO -- : Writing /var/www/quickcard/public/assets/application-4bcda1a2ad86133d1f3e33b2c53561990c0bd5c5e237e227357708bb00a21e7d.css.gz
I, [2022-06-21T14:19:36.585850 #8]  INFO -- : Writing /var/www/quickcard/public/assets/img/main3-9d715e6c156473fea20e2df822b880ce16f8d57b2de6e50e56d0bea18e9f2a27.jpg

### Docker File

> 

```
FROM ruby:2.7.2
ENV RAILS_ROOT /var/www/quickcard
ENV BUNDLE_VERSION 2.1.4
ENV BUNDLE_PATH usr/local/bundle/gems
ENV RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT true
ENV RAILS_PORT 5000
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential \
git \
libxml2-dev \
libpq-dev \
libxslt-dev \
nodejs \
yarn \
imagemagick \
tzdata \
less \
&& rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN gem install bundler --version "$BUNDLE_VERSION"
RUN bundle config set path $BUNDLE_PATH
RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT
ADD Gemfile Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
COPY yarn.lock yarn.lock
RUN bundle install
EXPOSE $RAILS_PORT
RUN ln -s $RAILS_ROOT/config/systemd/puma.service /etc/systemd/system/quickcard
COPY . .
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn install --check-files
RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
RUN ls /var/www/quickcard/public
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb"]
```

### Compose File

> 

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  app:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    command: ['bundle','exec','rails','s','-p','5000','-e','development', '-b', '0.0.0.0']
    # environment:
    #   RAILS_ENV: production
    volumes:
      - /var/wwww/quickcard
      - /var/wwww/quickcard/public
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
  sidekiq:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
    # environment:
    #   RAILS_ENV: production
    volumes:
      - /var/wwww/quickcard/tmp
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./nginx.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./log-nginx:/var/log/nginx/
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

### Nginx conf file

> 

```
upstream puma {
   server app:5000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server deferred;
    index index.html index.htm;
    access_log /var/www/quickcard/log/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/quickcard/log/nginx.error.log;
    location / {
        root /var/www/quickcard/public;
        proxy_pass http://puma;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

    }

    location /api {
        root /var/www/quickcard/public/;
        proxy_pass http://puma;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

    }

    location ^~ /assets/ {
    rewrite /var/www/quickcard(/assets/.*) $1;
    root /var/www/quickcard/public/;
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "";
  }

    # location ^~ /assets/ {
    #       root /var/www/quickcard/public/;
    #       gzip_static on;
    #       expires max;
    #       add_header Cache-Control public;
    # }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```